# Ag-grid actual number of rows in table

Tags: html, css, reactjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in my react project and I started creating custom pagination because I needed some more things to be shown.
Right now it looks like this:

[image]

Top pagination is the default one from ag-grid, second one is my custom.
Of course I am using [Pagination api](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/#pagination-api) props to show all of those things.

The problem here is that I don't know how to get first elements of pagination so numbers that show which rows are actually shown - "23 to 33". There is no props in pagination api of ag-grid so I had to manage it by myself. How can I get those things from API, is it even possible?

[image]

I see only this props and there is nothing about actual rows that are shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it by using pagination api props and multiplying paginationGetCurrentPage() by paginationGetPageSize()